# How can I add a material to only one side of a box?

Tags: aframe

How can I add a material to only one side of an Aframe geometry object such as a box? I need a box object that looks like a plane (scaled to flat) because I have child geometry objects, and need to be able to hold them outside of the plane area; however, since I've been making my box flat to look like a plane, it also makes the child objects flat as well.  So I figure if I can make the box look like a plane with a texture on only one side, it will fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

You can use [three.js MultiMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/MultiMaterial.html).

Most manual way would be to add a geometry to an entity, and then add a material manually:

```
var materials = [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ), // right
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } ), // left
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } ), // top
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } ), // bottom
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff } ), // back
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff00ff } )  // front
];
el.getObject3D('mesh').material = new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials);
```

Perhaps later on, someone could make a multimaterial A-Frame component to not have to touch JS.